# busca com select no banco de dados com registros repetidos

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select

Estou fazendo um `select` no meu banco, qual seja, *Postgres*, e estão vindo registros a mais..

Por exemplo, `id_pessoa` vem uns 10 registro a mais do que deveria vir..

```
SELECT pac.cns, 
    pac.cns_responsavel, 
    pac.cpf_responsavel, 
    pac.flag_alergico, 
    pac.flag_ativo, 
    pac.microarea, 
    pac.nome_responsavel, 
    pac.observacoes_alergias,
    pac.id_familia,
    pac.id_pessoa,
    pac.id_identidade_genero,
    pac.id_orientacao_sexual, 
    pend.bloco,
    pend.cep,
    pend.complemento,
    pend.nome_bairro,
    pend.nome_logradouro,
    pend.numero,
    pend.ponto_referencia,
    pend.id_bairro,
    pend.id_logradouro,
    pend.id_municipio,
    pend.id_pais,
    pend.id_uf,
    pesfis.carteira_profissional,
    pesfis.certidao_obito,
    pesfis.codigo_reservista,
    pesfis.cpf,
    pesfis.data_cadastro_pis_pasep,
    pesfis.data_obito,
    pesfis.emissao_carteira_profissional,
    pesfis.flag_ativo,
    pesfis.identidade_rg,
    pesfis.orgao_emissor_rg,
    pesfis.pis_pasep,
    pesfis.secao_eleitoral,
    pesfis.serie_carteira_profissional,
    pesfis.titulo_eleitor,
    pesfis.uf_orgao_emissor,
    pesfis.zona_eleitoral,
    pesfis.id_cbo,
    pesfis.id_escolaridade,
    pesfis.id_estado_civil,
    pesfis.id_etnia,
    pesfis.id_nacionalidade,
    pesfis.id_raca_cor,
    pesfis.id_sexo,
    pcarac.estatura,
    pcarac.flag_deficiente,
    pcarac.flag_doador,
    pcarac.peso,
    pcarac.id_cbor,
    pcarac.id_tipo_sanguineo,
    pcarac.id_orientacao,
    pcarac.id_identidade,
    pcarac 
FROM sau.pacientes pac, 
      glb.pessoas_enderecos pend, 
      glb.pessoas_fisicas pesfis, 
      glb.pessoas_caracteristicas pcarac,
      glb.pessoas pe
WHERE pac.id_pessoa= pend.id_pessoa 
        and pend.id_entidade = pesfis.id_entidade 
        and pend.id_pessoa= pesfis.id_pessoa 
        and pesfis.id_entidade = pcarac.id_entidade
        and pesfis.id_pessoa= pcarac.id_pessoa 
        and pcarac.id_entidade =  1;
```

Comment: replica o ambiente em sqlfiddle.com e poderia alterar a sintaxe para os joins de forma mais clara. Pessoalmente acho bem confusa essa forma de fazer os joins. E sim, o problema vai estar nos joins

Comment: Sem a estrutura de dados das suas tabelas fica dificil elaborar uma boa resposta.

Comment: Argh! joins implícitos, nem minha avô programa mais desse jeito

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Eu não tenho nenhuma experiência com o Postgres, mas geralmente isso acontece devido a um má relacionamento com outras tabelas (que fazem duplicar os registros).

Tenta utilizar DISTINCT após "SELECT" ou um GROUP BY após o "WHERE".

Answer (score 0):

Como você está relacionando várias tabelas, a consulta retornar várias o mesmo registro toda vez que ele conseguir encontrar o registro pesquisado nas tabelas.
Por exemplo, tem um registro na tabela sau.pacientes e esse registro possui dois registro relacionados na tabela glb.pessoas_enderecos, então, devido ao relacionamento esse select iria retornar duas linhas.

Faça o select abaixo para ver o que está repetindo:

```
SELECT *
FROM sau.pacientes pac, 
      glb.pessoas_enderecos pend, 
      glb.pessoas_fisicas pesfis, 
      glb.pessoas_caracteristicas pcarac,
      glb.pessoas pe
WHERE pac.id_pessoa= pend.id_pessoa 
        and pend.id_entidade = pesfis.id_entidade 
        and pend.id_pessoa= pesfis.id_pessoa 
        and pesfis.id_entidade = pcarac.id_entidade
        and pesfis.id_pessoa= pcarac.id_pessoa 
        and pcarac.id_entidade =  1;
```